# How to handle WM_SETCURSOR in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, wndproc

In my media player application, I hid the cursor using `SetCursor(NULL)` and to make sure that Windows does not reset the cursor state, I handled `WM_SETCURSOR` in my `WndProc` method.

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    switch (m.Msg)
    {
        case WM.SETCURSOR:
            base.WndProc(ref m);
            int lowWord = (m.LParam.ToInt32() << 16) >> 16;
            if (lowWord == HTCLIENT && FullScreen)
            {
                SetCursor(IntPtr.Zero); // hides cursor
                m.Result = (IntPtr)1; // return TRUE; equivalent in C++
            }
            return;
    }
}
```

However when the cursor is in the client area (aka `LOWORD(lParam) == HTCLIENT`), `WM_SETCURSOR` is never triggered in `WndProc`. So I never actually get the `WM_SETCURSOR` message when the cursor is in the client area and only get it when `LOWORD(lParam) != HTCLIENT`.

However in Spy++, it clearly shows that the application received the `WM_SETCURSOR` and `WM_MOUSEMOVE` messages.

Where is the message getting lost/handled? What do I have to do in order to receive the `WM_SETCURSOR` message in C#?

Comment: I don't know the answer off the top of my head. But why can't you just set the form's cursor?

Comment: I don't know why it can't work for you. I've tested a simple code and it works like a charm.

Comment: Are you sure the `HTCLIENT = 1`?

Comment: Looks like that the `Fullscreen` is false? Your code should work because I've tested. BTW, you should be sure `WM_SETCURSOR = 0x20` and `HTCLIENT = 1`.

Comment: @King Strange, when I put a breakpoint on the line after `case WM.SETCURSOR`, it only breaks once, during application startup. It doesn't break after that, even if the mouse is moving on top of the form.

Comment: @azian.otaku I think you should make a totally new demo, just add the code above. You don't need breakpoint here, especially in a `WndProc`, you can use `System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print` instead to see if it jumps in the case block.

Comment: @King okay I can confirm that it does send in a demo project I created. Now I have no idea why it isn't firing in my own project.

Comment: @azian.otaku does your form have any other control covering its surface, such as a `Panel` with `Dock = DockStyle.Fill`?

Comment: @King I have multiple `Panel`'s covering my application, although I thought that `WndProc` captures messages from the entire application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My application has several panels covering the application. So another user pointed out to me kindly that since every control has its own `WndProc`, the `WM_SETCURSOR` method wasn't being passed on to the form underneath it. In order to receive those messages, I would have to override each of those panels with its own `WndProc` method.

However the above code does work if there are no controls covering the form where the cursor is.